# Google Orgchart graph and the text for existing connections (between nodes)

Tags: javascript, api, treeview, google-visualization

I have a question about [Visualization: Google Organizational Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?csw=1#Configuration_Options)

Everything is perfect. The only thing I want is to add possible comments (some text) for existing connections between the nodes. How can I do that?

P.S. I see I can add ToolTips for each node. But what about text between the connected nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if anyone is interested in my solution, here it is:

```
  <style>/*please add styles after .js files, so it won't be overwritten*/
    .google-visualization-orgchart-connrow-medium {
        height: 64px;/*changed to a higher value so I could put some text in between nodes*/
    }
    .label{
        color:red; font-style:italic; border:1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:-60px;
    }
  </style>
```

Please add `<div class="label">My text between nodes</div>` right inside the node string value.
Example:

```
data.addRows([
  ...
    ['John<div class="label">Brother</div>', 'Lewis'],
  ...
]);
```